# Change cache path for electron js application

Tags: electron, electron-packager

By default electron stores the cache in the following path,

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\\Cache

For some reason, I want to change this path, is it possible?

Comment: Any chance you have found out how now? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's currently possible, but I think it will be when [this PR](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/19693) gets merged.